# TODO comments in JavaScript files in Zend Studio (Eclipse) do not show in Tasks

Tags: javascript, php, eclipse, zend-framework

TODOs in PHP files show in Tasks view but TODOs in JavaScript files do not.

To isolate any strange settings in my current project, I have created a new project (both Zend Framework and just JavaScript projects) and created a .js file with a //TODO comment.  The comment does not show in my Tasks view.

I have looked at all of the obvious stuff.  My Preferences->JavaScript->Validator->Task Tags settings are set to recognize @TODO as well as TODO.  I have tried making changes to these tags and resaving to try to get Eclipse to rebuild, to no avail.

Project->Builders is set to use 'JavaScript Validator', 'Validation', and 'Script Builder'.

Manually cleaning and rebuilding the project has no effect.

It appears this is experienced in non Zend Studio Eclipse builds as well.